# Lost Bitcoin-qt password

Tags: bitcoin-core

I have a friend (yes it's actually a friend and not me) who lost his password for their Bitcoin-qt wallet and can't access is Bitcoin.  The wallet is installed on the hard drive of a MacBook and he doesn't know any of the characters   Does anyone know how we can get this coin back without his wallet password?

Comment: If the password is more than a handful of characters long, and your friend has absolutely no idea what some of the character can be. Unfortunately no one can help you. Does he have the private key though?                                     However, if he knows some of the characters of the password. Then famous Dave can help, his link https://walletrecoveryservices.com

Comment: He doesn't know any of the characters.  I assume he's out of luck but I'm curious if anyone has any creative solutions.

Comment: Does he know anything about the password? Length? characters or numbers or both? Parts of the password?

Answer (score -2):

"Creative solution" would be to forget about his wallet and to join [Large Bitcoin Collider](https://lbc.cryptoguru.org) project, he might "recover" another lost wallet one day.

Also, if he had 1000 BTC or more in his wallet, some hypnosis-guru might help him to remember his password.

Answer (score -2):

You keys are stored in file wallet.dat
You can use brute force for wallet.dat